# Python: Replacing a string with unique replacements

Tags: python, regex, string, string-substitution

I'm reading a file and I need to replace certain empty tags ([[Image:]]).

The problem is every replacement has to be unique.

Here's the code:

```
import re
import codecs

re_imagematch = re.compile('(\[\[Image:([^\]]+)?\]\])')

wf = codecs.open('converted.wiki', "r", "utf-8")
wikilines = wf.readlines()
wf.close()

imgidx = 0
for i in range(0,len(wikilines)):
 if re_imagematch.search(wikilines[i]):
  print 'MATCH #######################################################'
  print wikilines[i]
  wikilines[i] = re_imagematch.sub('[[Image:%s_%s.%s]]' % ('outname', imgidx, 'extension'), wikilines[i])
  print wikilines[i]
  imgidx += 1
```

This does not work, as there can be many tags in one line:

Here's the input file.

```
[[Image:]][[Image:]]
[[Image:]]
```

This is what the output should look like:

```
[[Image:outname_0.extension]][Image:outname_1.extension]]
[[Image:outname_2.extension]]
```

This is what it currently looks likeö

```
[[Image:outname_0.extension]][Image:outname_0.extension]]
[[Image:outname_1.extension]]
```

I tried using a replacement function, the problem is this function gets only called once per line using re.sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a simple string replacement wrapped in a `while` loop:

```py
s = '[[Image:]][[Image:]]\n[[Image:]]'
pattern = '[[Image:]]'
i = 0
while s.find(pattern) >= 0:
    s = s.replace(pattern, '[[Image:outname_' + str(i) + '.extension]]', 1)
    i += 1
print s
```

Comment: Since I'm not a big expert in Python, and neither are the people here that have to understand this too, I am accepting your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) here and take some advantage of the fact that default arguments are calculated when function is created and value of mutable default arguments [can persist between function calls.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

```
from itertools import count

def rep(m, cnt=count()):
    return '[[Image:%s_%s.%s]]' % ('outname', next(cnt) , 'extension')
```

This function will be invoked for each match found and it'll use a new value for each replacement.

So, you simply need to change this line in your code:

```
wikilines[i] = re_imagematch.sub(rep, wikilines[i])
```

**Demo:**

```
def rep(m, count=count()):
    return str(next(count))

>>> re.sub(r'a', rep, 'aaa')
'012'
```

To get the current counter value:

```
>>> from copy import copy
>>> next(copy(rep.__defaults__[0])) - 1
2
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary although the current counter value works, it might be easier to wrap in a class that exposes a property of the previously yielded value... Although - it's quite a bit more work :p